# SSLProtocolException when making GET request

Tags: android, https

We have a sdk which can integrated in an android app. The sdk makes some HTTP/HTTPS GET requests.
Here is the code that does this.

```
public boolean sendDataToServer(String url) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode != 200) {
            String responseBody = getAndClose(conn.getErrorStream());
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private  String getAndClose(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        return content.toString();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

However with one app it is giving the following error when it is trying to connect using HTTPS

```
IOExcetion while sending the data to server javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x650ed348: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x5e84cf1c:0x00000000)
```

In the same device if I install another app with the sdk and make same GET request it works fine and I get a 200 OK response.

Why this might be happening and how to prevent this ?

Comment: You need the SSLCertificate for the HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpUrlConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory() method.

```
    final TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = new X509Certificate[0];
            return x509Certificates;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       final String authType) {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       final String authType) {
        }
    }};

    SSLContext ctx = null;

    ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, certs, new SecureRandom());



    HttpUrlConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory();
```